# Differentiable and non-differentiable problem in the book "Convex optimization"

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

I am reading the book "Convex optimization". In example 4.3 the author says that 
$$||Ax-b||_2$$ is not differentiable at any point where $Ax-b=0$ where $A$ is a matrix of size $n\times m$ and $x,b$ are a vectors of $m$ and $n$ rows respectively. On the other hand, he says that $||ax-b||_2^2$ is differentiable. Can any body explain how?

My logic for $||Ax-b||_2$:

I can understand that since norm is always positive so for a certain range of $x$ the value $Ax-b$ will first decrease and then increase (will make a kind of V shape). At the time when it touches zero its derivative switches from negative to positive (or vice versa) with any increment in the $x$ so we can say that it is non-differentiable. But this logic does not apply to $||Ax-b||_2^2$. Can any body help me in understanding it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Switching signs can be done in non-violent ways. Just look at $f(x) = x^2$ for $x=0$. It has a very smooth switch of sign of it's derivative there. But what happens if you take the square root of it?

Comment: @Miguel : that is not what we are talking about. What happens is the opposite. The square root comes in **after** the squaring. Not the other way around.

Comment: The square root $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. Squaring again makes the square root disappear, and now you have a polynomial. I was trying to say the same as @mathreadler with different words.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at it in $1$ dimension. There, $A$ becomes a real number, $x$ is a single variable, and $b$ is a number. The first expression becomes

$$|ax-b|$$

which is differentiable (and, indeed, linear) around all $x$ for which $ax-b\neq 0$, but it is not differentiable if $ax-b=0$ (unless $a=b=0$, in which case the expression is always $0$).

The second expression, however, becomes $$|ax-b|^2$$ which is the same as $$(ax-b)^2$$

which is a polynomial function and therefore differentiable everywhere.

---

Now, in many dimensions, something fairly similar happens. If you vary just one variable of the vector $x$, you get a linear function under the absolute value which has a "breaking" point where it reaches zero, and the second function is just a polynomial.

Comment: my question is why is it not differentiable? I am sorry for asking a very basic question but I really do not know the answer.

Comment: @FrankMoses Do you know why $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: I do not know why $|x|$ is not differentiable. I just can guess that if we look at the graph then there is a jerk at $x=0$ that is why maybe it is not differentiable

Comment: @FrankMoses Don't take this the wrong way, please, but I have to say this: If you do not know why $|x|$ is not differentiable, then you shuoldn't be learning convex optimization. Knowing basic calculus is **vital** for learning more advanced topics, and you clearly have only a basic understanding of derivatives and differentiability. I strongly suggest you take a couple of days (or more) to read through a basic text on calculus before you go and learn more advanced topics...

Comment: @FrankMoses Take it as a friendly warning. What you are doing is trying to run before learning to walk. It's possible, but damn hard and a bad idea in general.

Comment: I agree with you and I am thankful to you for your advice. No hard feelings. I will go through some of the basic calculus before learning about advanced topics

Comment: @FrankMoses Also, just to answer the question with $|x|$, the function is not differentiable at $x=0$ because its left derivative is $-1$, and its right derivative is $1$ - for differentiable functions, the two derivatives must match.

Comment: not zero I think $-1$

Comment: @FrankMoses Heh, yeah.

Comment: @FrankMoses, not to pile on here, but another Math.SE poster recently also demonstrated some struggles with the necessary calculus, so it's fresh in my mind. It's important to master not just single-variable differential calculus, but multivariable differential calculus as well---specifically gradients, Hessians. Look at Appendix A of the Convex Optimization book you're reading---everything there should be comfortable before diving too deeply into the book.